# Firewall Rule Testing - telnet failing

Tags: firewall, telnet

1. I am testing firewall rules but the telnet is failing.
2. The firewallrules have been implemented but the target server is not listening
   on the servers.
3. How can I enable the target server ports to listen

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: You'll need to give some more info than that, like what are your firewall rules, which ports do you want to listen, distro, etc

Answer (score 2):

quickest would be to start a netcat listener, e.g. `nc -l 23` or `ncat -l 23` on the server, then use `echo foo | nc server 23` or such on clients to throw data at the server